# python: sum similar values in list

Tags: python, list, sum

Is there an easy way to sum all similar values in a list using list comprehensions?

i.e. input:

```
[1, 2, 1, 3, 3]
```

expected output:

```
[6, 2, 2] (sorted)
```

I tried using zip, but it only works for max 2 similar values:

```
[x + y for (x, y) in zip(l[:-1], l[1:]) if x == y]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Counter.

```
from collections import Counter
[x*c for x,c in Counter([1, 2, 1, 3, 3]).items()]
```

Comment: I like the way Counter :)

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import groupby
a=[1, 2, 1,1,4,5,5,5,5, 3, 3]

print sorted([sum(g) for i,g in groupby(sorted(a))],reverse=True)

#output=[20, 6, 4, 3, 2]
```

explantion for the code

1. first sort the list using `sorted(a)`
2. perform [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to make groupf of similar elements
3. from each group use `sum()`

Comment: Shouldn't it be ; print sorted([sum(g) for i,g in groupby(sorted(a))],reverse=True) ? Otherwise, i see TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @myildirim please check now. i have tested it. i am not getting any error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` for this, this will take `O(N)` time.:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst = [1, 2, 1, 3, 3]
>>> [k*v for k, v in Counter(lst).iteritems()]
[2, 2, 6]
```

Here `Counter()` returns the count of each unique item, and then we multiply those numbers with their count to get the sum.